# Do I need to create one or more index in application

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, indexing, cluster-computing, lumen

I am a newbie in elastic search. I want to know how many indexes I need to create using elastic? Do I need to create the index as per entity? or do I need to create only one index in which all my entities resides?
If I create an index entity wise how can I merge all index responses to get only a single response as an output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depends of the context, and dataset you need to index, but you have the possibility to search on cluster wide with `/_search` without specifying a indice name

You still have a limit on indice / shard usage base on your server capacity, each shard will be an instance in lucence so will use memory.

Generally speaking you want to limit indice numbers, but it's really depends on needs